# ¿Cómo puedo des habilitar botón de la fila?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde realizo una operación, por fila. Deseo poder des habilitar  el botón de esa fila. Al momento de presionar el botón.

```
<table id="tableDespacho" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Cantidad
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">Clasificacion
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text"> <input type="hidden" name="cantidadReal" value="<?php echo $row['Cantidad']; ?>"></td>
            <td data-name="Clasificacion" class="editable Clasificacion" data-type="select"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="save(this)" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip">
                </button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>





function save(btn) {
var clasificacion = $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:eq(12)').text();

var cantidad = $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:eq(11)').text();

var code = $("input[name=codigo]").val();


$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'JSON/entradaJSON.php',
data: {
'clasificacion': clasificacion,
'cantidad': cantidad,
'code': code
},
success: function(response) {

//METODO PARA DISABLEAR BOTON


},
error: function() {
toastr.error('ERROR', 'Movimiento de Bodega', {
progressBar: true,
closeButton: true
});
}
});



}
```

Como obtengo el botón de esa fila para agregar un disable al botón

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade este codigo dentro del callback success del Ajax

```
btn.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 1):

Agarre tu **HTML** e hice 3 filas con 3 botones e implemente un evento **click** para que veas como se pudiera deshabilitar el botón:

```js
$(".btn").on("click",(e) => {

 $(e.target).attr("disabled",true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableDespacho" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Cantidad
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">Clasificacion
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text"> 
          2
        </td>
        <td data-name="Clasificacion" class="editable Clasificacion" data-type="select">
          5
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text"> 
          1
        </td>
        <td data-name="Clasificacion" class="editable Clasificacion" data-type="select">
          4
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text"> 
          3
        </td>
        <td data-name="Clasificacion" class="editable Clasificacion" data-type="select">
          8
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-success done" data-toggle="tooltip">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ahora en tu **ajax** en el `success` seria así:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'JSON/entradaJSON.php',
  data: {
    'clasificacion': clasificacion,
    'cantidad': cantidad,
    'code': code
  },
  success: function(response) {

    $(btn).attr("disabled",true);

  }
```